# SSH tunnelling machine at client's home

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ssh, tunnel

I would like to access a service with a specific IP from anywhere around the world. This IP is the home IP of my client.

I am thinking of setting up a computer (or raspberry pi) which is connected to his home wifi. This device will have openport.io installed which allows me to tunnel to it even if my client's home ip is dynamic.

Some requirements for the device:

1. Since it's at my client's home, I won't have convenient physical
   access to it.
2. The device should be robust - meaning it crashes I can just call my client to give it a restart and it will connect to the wifi and
   then fire up openport automatically.

**NOTE** I do not have any problems with dynamic dns because openport.io is solves my problem already

What kind of device is good for my purpose?

Comment: Use [tor](http://unethicalblogger.com/2012/06/13/ssh-as-a-hidden-service.html) network.

Comment: @IporSircer I don't need a new IP. I need my client's IP

Comment: use any of the dyndns services. Plenty of dns servers will dynamically a dns entry like noip.com - ip changes but dns to access it is updated regularly

Answer (score 1):

Remember to make absolutely sure that whatever you set up on that machine is not a possible entrance door for unwanted visitors in your clients network.

I would say the main deciding factors here are performance, price and user base. A large user base like the pi has means a more thoroughly tested device and high changes of finding solutions if you run into trouble.

From the little information you give it sounds like about any typical arm based board will serve your purpose in an efficient way. However if possible I would always connect a stationary machine via ethernet cable in favor of wifi. It's faster, more reliable, easier to set up and more energy efficient.